# Gnome 3 styling on Fedora 31 corrupted: Black Background in certain apps

Tags: fedora, gnome-3, gnome-shell

Since an update several weeks ago, the styling of certain applications on my fedora machine got corrupted and are showing black background instead of white. Please see the screen shots attached. It used to be the case for Nautilus' background as well until I changed the shell theme. Could someone point me in the right direction which files should be edited? Note: I have both KDE and Gnome installed on this machine. [image: gnome calculator with black background screen]
[image: gnome tweak tool with black background display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by renaming the settings files in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`:

```sh
cd ~/.config/gtk-3.0
mv colors.css colors.css.old
```

After doing that, be sure to reload gnome (or restart Linux)